# How can I get a "printable page" in the whole window without Chrome interfering?

Tags: google-chrome

Suppose I want to view
http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/howto_use_local_group_policy_editor_tweak_your_pc

and I want to see it on one page, without Google intervening.

I want to go to the printable version

http://www.maximumpc.com/print/article/howtos/howto_use_local_group_policy_editor_tweak_your_pc

For a moment I get what I would like

[image]

---

But then that changes very quickly

Chrome intervenes and I get this below

How do I get Chrome to not intervene?

I don't want it to become that which is shown below

[image]

In Internet Explorer, ok initially the print dialog comes up, but you can cancel it, and then choose it keep the window open. I've tested this in IE 8 in XP and Win7, and in an earlier IE like IE7. But I can't keep the window open in Chrome and without chrome's print dialog box in it.

I want Chrome to be able to do as IE does and allow the whole page to appear without the print dialog embedded in it or over it.  I understand that firefox can do it as well as IE, so Chrome seems to be the funny one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it a few times out of luck and now I've figured out how I did it.

**The procedure where it closes, i.e. what not to do, is when you**

- Open the non-printable page (it has the link to the printable version)
- Open the printable version from there, click and it opens in a new tab.
- You may close the non-printable or not, it doesn't change the result in this scenario.
- When the print dialog comes up in the printable page, hit cancel, and the printable document "infuriatingly" closes.

---

**Here is how to do it so it works:**

- Open the non-printable page (it has the link to the printable version)
- DO NOT CLICK THE PRINTABLE LINK
- Right click the printable link and copy it to the clipboard.
  (You do not have to have opened the non-printable page, but get that link)
- Paste the printable link into the address bar in a new tab or the same tab as the non-printable page was in. It wasn't matter what tab you do it in.
- When the print dialog comes up  within the document, hit cancel in the printable document, and the printable document will remain open.

---

And by the way, there is an option within the Chrome print preview to make the system dialog box come up. "Print using system dialog  ctrl shift p". That will bring up the system dialog, but when you click cancel, you're in the same boat as with the Chrome print dialog, i.e., use the first scenario and it will close as soon as you hit cancel, use the second scenario and it will stay open.

Comment: @AlEverett Furthermore, as we have noticed, Other browsers don't do this, only Chrome. So this idea you mildly suggest that it's written in the code to close the thing, I just don't see it, if you were correct about that, then it'd mean that technically, FF and IE are behaving wrongly, and I doubt that you want to claim that, you seem to insist it's just the code.  I'd like to see some examples of the many you speak of. Or since you claim to have written some <cough>.